# How to install Gensim version 0.11.1 on Windows 10 Machine?

Tags: python, pip, conda, gensim

I have anaconda and Pip installed. I tried doing

```
conda install -c anaconda gensim-0.11.1
```

but it couldn't find the package and the following msg was thrown on the PowerShell.

```
Using Anaconda Cloud api site https://api.anaconda.org
Fetching package metadata: ......
Solving package specifications: .
Error:  Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - gensim-0.11.1

You can search for this package on anaconda.org with

    anaconda search -t conda gensim-0.11.1
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

--Conda works well with the machine but even help with Pip would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any reason you need the `0.11.1` version?  That version hasn't been specifically built as a conda package apparently.

At the moment, `conda install gensim` will easily give you version `0.12.4`.

If you really need version `0.11.1`, first

```
conda install scipy pip
```

then

```
pip install gensim==0.11.1
```